# Use Advanced Custom Fields - replace line of code that hardcodes the tag into the template

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to tweak a page template for a WordPress site that uses Advanced Custom Fields and I am stuck on replacing this line of code (which hard codes the tag test123 in the template):

```
<?php   $tag_query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => 'test123' ) );   ?>
```

This is the relevant code currently in the template file

```
<?php   
$blog_tag   = get_field('blog_tag');
?>
<?php   $tag_query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => 'test123' ) );   ?>
<?php while ($tag_query -> have_posts()) : $tag_query -> the_post(); ?>
<div id="blog" class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card card-plain">
        <div class="card-image no-shadow"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <div class="atvImg">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div></a>
        <div class="card-content">
            <h6 class="categories text-success"><?php the_category(', ')?></h6>

            <header class="entry-header">
                <h3 class="card-title"><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I created a new custom field with field name "blog_tag". When editing the Wordpress Page I can choose the tags etc so this bit seems aok.

[image]

[image]
I was hoping for a simple solution like this to just replace the one line of code in the template but I can't get it to work:

```
<?php   $tag_query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => 'echo $blog_tag;' ) );   ?>
```

The display is fine - just want to make the tag(s) dynamic instead of hardcoded.

I have tried about 10 different combinations of code that I have found from searching for a solution but I can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

ps my php is very limited.

Comment: Let me know which parameter you have set for return value in Advanced Custom Field? like Term Object OR Term ID

Comment: Term ID at the moment (not sure if that is correct?) Thanks.

Comment: If you can attach full screenshot of advanced custom field and also attach one of the post with this field display so It is easy to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Display post by Using ONE Tag

> Display post by tag id in same way. You just need to change the tag parameter name. This will display post which are tagged with 13 tag id. Here 13 is tag ids which is used just for example to explain in better way.

```
$tag_query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag_id' => '13' ) );
```

---

### Display posts from either tag

> To display posts from either tag you need to use tag__in. This will return posts from either tag id.

```
$tag_query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__in' => '13, 27' ) );
```

---

> **Now, you can try below code to fix your issue.**

```
<?php $tag_query = new WP_Query(array('tag__in' => $blog_tag)); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Tanmay. I just tried that code. But no success. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user3643520 I have updated my answer so you can just try it. Hope it is work perfectly.

Comment: Sensational! Thanks Tamnay - this one works a treat 
`<?php $tag_query = new WP_Query(array('tag__in' => $blog_tag)); ?>`. The `tag__and` version did not work. Thanks so much for your help :)